# Emacs: How does one run RSpec?

Tags: emacs, rspec

How does one run `rspec-mode` in emacs? What I have tried is:

- Go to spec file in Emacs
- Run `M-x rspec-verify-all`

I get the following output in `*rspec-compilation*` buffer

```
-*- mode: rspec-compilation; default-directory: "~/mydir" -*-
RSpec Compilation started at Sun Feb 15 21:31:36

bundle exec rake spec SPEC_OPTS='--options /Users/rabraham/mydir/.rspec' SPEC='/Users/rabraham/mydir/spec'

RSpec Compilation finished at Sun Feb 15 21:31:39
```

No tests are run. I have a failing test but that is not caught. Is there a tutorial on running rspec-mode in Emacs?

Comment: Can you paste the command and output you usually run to create the failing test you mention? At least then we can compare the command you're running to the command Emacs runs above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rake "spec" task by default. You should configure your Rakefile like described [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/rake-task)